# Algunos directorio aparecen con un candado - Cambio permisos con CHMOD pero sigue igual

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Algunos directorio me aparecen con un candado.
¿Cómo puedo cambiar permisos para que pueda utilizarlo sin problema sin tener que utilizar la terminal?

He probado aplicar un chmod -R 744 a los directorio, pero sigue igual. ¿Qué sucede?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es ud. el dueño o intentó como root?

Comment: Sí, soy el dueño. Es algo que subí a github, y cuando lo descarge, me sale de esta manera.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba:

`sudo chown -R tu_usuario_normal:tu_usuario_normal nombre_carpeta`

Y luego:

`chmod -R 777 nombre_carpeta`

Esto hará que todo lo que esté dentro de esas carpetas tengan los 3 permisos (leer, escribir y ejecutar) y que además puedas accederlos sin usuario root.

Comment: Solucionado. No estoy seguro si es lo propio dar todos los permisos, pero al menos ha quedado solucionado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Concuerdo, no es lo óptimo, pero en el caso de los repositorios de github normalmente son proyectos de programación, y me termina fastidiando mucho en el visual studio code debido a permisos y esas cosas, aparte cuándo vuelves a actualizar el repo igual github te pone de nuevo los permisos, así que pues... Al yo cansarme de tanto hacer eso prefiero simplemente que se actualicen todos los permisos en cascada.